# CS50 Greedy Need Advice

Tags: c, cs50

I am doing the cs50 problem set "Greedy". Basically asking the user for how much change is owed and then outputting the minimum amount of coins that can equal the inputed amount. It works perfectly, except when I input 4.2 it outputs 22 when it should output 18.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    float n;
    do
    {
        n = get_float("How much change is owed?\n");
    }
    while(n == EOF);

    int cents = (int)(n * 100);
    int minimumamountofcoins = 0;
    if (cents/25 >= 1){
        while (cents/25 >= 1)
        {
            cents -= 25;
            minimumamountofcoins++;
        }

    }
    if (cents/10 >= 1){
        while (cents/10 >= 1)
        {
            cents -= 10;
            minimumamountofcoins++;
        }
    }
    if(cents/5 >= 1){
        while (cents/5 >= 1)
        {
            cents -= 5;
            minimumamountofcoins++;
        }
    }
    if (cents/1 >= 1){
        while (cents/1 >= 1)
        {
            cents -= 1;
            minimumamountofcoins++;
        }
    }
    printf("The minimum amount of coins is %d\n", minimumamountofcoins);
}
```

Comment: try to step through it with a debugger. You can also ditch the if clauses before the while loop, they basically test the same thing.

Comment: Yet another "change" question amongst thousands. Stay away from floating point, and do a bit of research please.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/45703316/2410359

Comment: Use `int` insted of `float` for input.

Comment: Try to print cents after `int cents = (int)(n * 100);`. Also all `if` conditions are redundant, you can remove them.

Comment: 1) Do not convert and scale `float` money to `int` with `int cents = (int)(n * 100);`  `long cents = lround(n * 100.0);` is better.   2) Do not use `float` with money.  Typical C data types **all** have trouble with money - `float/char` are the worst.

Comment: BTW Was the specification of [get_float](https://reference.cs50.net/cs50/get_float) changed?

Comment: Yup - even before I opened it, I was waiting for 'float n;' :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is an issue with the conversion from float to int. When you try to convert from dollars to cents, you do so with this line of code:

```
int cents = (int)(n * 100);
```

However, this line of code, for $4.20, is returning a cent value of 419. This is a problem with rounding and floats, as 4.2 * 100 is returning 419.99999999 instead of 420.0000000, and integer casting truncates instead of rounding. This problem also occurs with $4.18, and probably other values as well.

To prevent this, add 0.5 before the cast, like so:

```
int cents = (int)(n * 100 + 0.5);
```

This will ensure that the rounding takes place in the proper direction, as you are never off by more that a trivial float error.

Using the `math.h` library, you could also use the `roundf()` function, which will work in the case of negative numbers, just in case.

```
int cents = (int)(roundf(n*100));
```

Comment: `(int)(n * 100 + 0.5)` likely will meet basic needs but fails under various conditions including negative, large numbers and others.  C has about a dozen rounding functions in `<math.h>`.  Use the best tool in the shed.

Comment: Fair enough. Since the asker is using dollars, I assumed that they could never be negative, but I'll edit the post to include a better rounding method.

Comment: Minor: " integer casting rounds down" --> "integer casting truncates the fraction"  This differs, again, with - numbers.

Comment: Also true, will fix as well

Comment: Some numerical trivia for UnknowableIneffable:  Consider the difference between `roundf(n*100)` and `round(n*100.0)`.  With values near +/-x.xx5, the first can round the wrong way due to inexactness of `some_float_n*some_int_100` where `n*100.0` will compute as `double` and the typical extra precision provides correct results.

Comment: I was not aware of that at all! Thanks for the info, although I won't change the post, as it's not necessary to in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use the round function to round up your numbers. In this part of your code, you need to add the round function.

```c
int cents = (int)(n * 100);
```

It has to be like this:

```c
cents = round(n * 100);
```

If you have other such problems, you can use a debugger such as debug50, in  which you put a breakpoint by clicking in the right of the line number, then in your terminal window(the one where you execute clang) you should type:

```
~/pset1/cash/ $ debug50 ./cash
```

Or whatever your program is called. This will open the debugger and inside it you will find all the variables and what they are equal to. Press on the button next to the play button to move one line of code forward.